# Query takes long due to using views. How can i merge into simple query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which uses a view to return data, but it seems to be going for more than a minute to request back from the server.

I use this code :

```
SELECT CROP_CLASS As Closed, SUM(ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage, SUM(delivered) AS SumofTonnage
FROM dbo.vCurrentParcelStatus 
WHERE CropSeasonsID = @cropseason AND CURRENTSTATUS = '3'
GROUP BY CROP_CLASS
ORDER BY CROP_CLASS ASC
```

This takes more than a minute but gives me what I am looking for. It requests data from vCurrentParcelStatus below:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.CaneParcel.geoid, MAX(dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.CurrentStatus) AS CURRENTSTATUS, dbo.CaneParcel.ACREAGE, 
                  dbo.CaneParcel.VARIETY, dbo.CaneParcel.FARMER, dbo.CaneParcel.BRANCH, dbo.CaneParcel.DATE_PLANT, dbo.CaneParcel.CROP_CLASS, 
                  SUM(ROUND(dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.delivered, 1)) AS delivered, SUM(dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.number_deliveries) AS number_deliveries, 
                  dbo.CaneParcel.ASSN, dbo.CaneParcel.PRODUCTION, dbo.CaneParcel.REAPING_LE, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id, 
                  dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.crop_season, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.CropSeasonsID
FROM         dbo.CaneParcel INNER JOIN
                  dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp ON dbo.CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id
GROUP BY dbo.CaneParcel.geoid, dbo.CaneParcel.ACREAGE, dbo.CaneParcel.VARIETY, dbo.CaneParcel.FARMER, dbo.CaneParcel.BRANCH, dbo.CaneParcel.DATE_PLANT, 
                  dbo.CaneParcel.CROP_CLASS, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id, dbo.CaneParcel.ASSN, dbo.CaneParcel.PRODUCTION, dbo.CaneParcel.REAPING_LE, 
                  dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.crop_season, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.CropSeasonsID
ORDER BY dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id
```

And the view above gets data from this view(vCurrentParcelStatusHelp) below:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT MAX(parcel_status) AS CurrentStatus, COUNT(tonnage) AS number_deliveries, SUM(tonnage_adjusted) AS delivered, parcel_id, 
                  farmer_owner_bsi, crop_season, CropSeasonsID
FROM         dbo.vDeliveryTons
GROUP BY parcel_id, farmer_owner_bsi, crop_season, CropSeasonsID
ORDER BY parcel_id
```

I tried this query but it does not give me the same results:

```
Select 
   CaneParcel.Crop_Class As Closed, 
   Sum(CaneParcel.Acreage) as SumOfTonnage,
   Sum(DeliveryTons.tonnage_adjusted) as SumOfTonnage
From 
    CaneParcel Left Join
    DeliveryTons On DeliveryTons.parcel_id  = CaneParcel.Field_ID Left Join
    FarmerGroups f On f.farmer_bsi = DeliveryTons.farmer_bsi Join
   (Select Distinct DeliveryTons.parcel_id From DeliveryTons Where parcel_status = 3 AND crop_season=3 and remarks = '') c On c.parcel_id = CaneParcel.Field_ID
Group By 
   CaneParcel.Crop_Class
```

DeliveryTons Table

```
id  crop_season parcel_id   reaping_code    farmer_pay_bsi  tonnage tonnage_adjusted    grabs   parcel_status   rejected    remarks delivery_status
77701   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    15.3625 15.3625 34.00   2   2       P
77702   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    17.4625 17.4625 43.50   2   2       P
77703   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    13.5875 13.5875 30.00   2   2       P
77704   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    19.0250 19.0250 44.00   2   2       P
77705   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    19.6375 19.6375 45.50   2   2       P
77706   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    16.2125 16.2125 36.50   2   2       P
77707   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    22.5375 22.5375 55.00   2   2       P
77708   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    18.1000 18.1000 38.00   2   2       P
77709   1   038-0358    CGP001  2064    23.0000 23.0000 55.50   2   2       P
77710   1   016-0482    BSFA156 7866    19.3000 19.3000 42.00   1   2       P
77711   1   016-0096    BSFA153 10024   15.2625 15.2625 34.00   1   2       P
77712   1   004-0684    BSFA155 10063   17.8125 17.8125 40.00   1   2       P
77713   1   004-0224    BSFA162 198 20.5125 20.5125 47.00   1   2       P
77714   1       BSFA160 212 16.0375 16.0375 0.00    0   2   NO_TICKET   P
77715   1       BSFA159 4570    12.3875 12.3875 0.00    0   2   NO_TICKET   P
77716   1   016-2473    BSFA151 9173    13.6875 13.6875 0.00    3   2       P
77717   1   016-1566    BSFA149 1094    15.7250 15.7250 32.00   1   2       P
77718   1       BSFA160 148 20.2125 20.2125 0.00    0   2   NO_TICKET   P
77719   1   016-1566    BSFA149 1094    12.7625 12.7625 26.00   2   2       P
77720   1   016-1566    BSFA149 1094    15.3875 15.3875 28.00   2   2       P
77721   1   016-2152    BSFA175 926 15.2625 15.2625 0.00    3   2       P
77722   1       BSFA175 5498    13.7250 13.7250 0.00    0   2   NO_TICKET   P
77723   1   016-2465    BSFA173 6529    13.6375 13.6375 0.00    3   2       P
77724   1   016-2373    BSFA177 3791    15.5000 15.5000 31.25   1   2       P
77725   1   016-1020    BSFA171 6468    16.1000 16.1000 19.00   1   2       P
77726   1       BSFA175 3019    13.1125 13.1125 0.00    0   2   NO_TICKET   P
77727   1   016-2465    BSFA173 6529    14.0750 14.0750 0.00    3   2       P
77728   1   016-0309    BSFA182 5311    11.8125 11.8125 26.50   1   2       P
```

CaneParcel Table:

```
geoid   FIELD_ID    BSI_CODE    ACREAGE CROP_CLASS  ASSN    FARMER  BRANCH
0   004-0567    47  7.359515    RATOON  CSCPA   MARIN,OMAR  COROZAL
1   004-0008    281 12.38654    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
2   004-0012    281 7.899037    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
3   004-0013    281 4.937749    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
4   004-0014    281 5.002847    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
5   004-0038    9050    6.731369    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID ISRAEL   COROZAL
6   004-0045    9028    4.120158    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,MIRIAM COROZAL
7   004-0039    9050    8.519387    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID ISRAEL   COROZAL
8   004-0147    289 14.801  RATOON  BSCFA-CZ    CAMPOS,ELEONAI  COROZAL
9   004-0572    47  5.878942    PLANTCANE   CSCPA   MARIN,OMAR  COROZAL
10  004-0030    281 14.33925    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
11  004-1150    281 7.306061    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
12  004-1152    281 3.814288    RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
13  004-0017    281 11.5479 RATOON  CSCPA   AKIERMAN,DAVID  COROZAL
28  004-0563    47  7.98629 RATOON  CSCPA   MARIN,OMAR  COROZAL
```

FarmerGroups Table:

```
ID  ASSN    BSI_CODE    FARMER  CROP_SEASON PROD_EST    BRANCH
10473   BSCFA-OW    5752    GARCIA,EUGENIO R    2   464 YO CREEK
10474   BSCFA-OW    8894    GARCIA,RAUL R   2   488 YO CREEK
10475   BSCFA-OW    4427    PECH,EVELIA 2   458 YO CREEK
10476   BSCFA-OW    5226    GONZALEZ,DALIA MARIA    2   195 YO CREEK
10477   BSCFA-OW    5753    GONZALEZ,ELVIRA 2   124 YO CREEK
10478   BSCFA-OW    9295    GONZALEZ,RAUL   2   138 YO CREEK
10479   BSCFA-OW    9996    GONZALEZ,TRANSITO   2   450 YO CREEK
10480   BSCFA-OW    10099   PERAZA,ALBERTA  2   830 YO CREEK
10481   BSCFA-OW    4537    GARCIA,SANTIAGO SILVERIO    2   167 YO CREEK
10482   BSCFA-OW    8573    ACK,AMELITA M   2   76  YO CREEK
10483   BSCFA-OW    7467    ACK,EUCARIO 2   96  YO CREEK
10484   BSCFA-OW    7468    ACK,MOISES  2   43  YO CREEK
10485   BSCFA-OW    1848    AGUIRRE,NENCIE  2   64  YO CREEK
10486   BSCFA-OW    4355    BLANCO,SILVIO   2   79  YO CREEK
10487   BSCFA-OW    4476    CAL,ALBERTA GARCIA  2   152 YO CREEK
10488   BSCFA-OW    4480    CAL,ENRIQUE 2   409 YO CREEK
10489   BSCFA-OW    2545    CAL,ERNESTO T   2   54  YO CREEK
10490   BSCFA-OW    6877    CAL,REMIGIO 2   76  YO CREEK
```

I am looking to get the Sum of Acreage and Sum of Tonnage from different Field_Is which have a max parcel status in delivery tons as 3 combining the tonnage if the status is 1 and 2 and there is a field id in the Delivery Tons table by BSI Code to also be able to get the association.

Comment: Define `This takes more than a minute`. You are doing aggregations on a table, joining a view that's doing aggregation on another view and who knows what's inside that view. Show your execution plan and see where the bottleneck is. And as @bjk116 says, "How are your indexes?"

Comment: What do you mean by indexes? More than a minute to give me the results I mean up to 2 minutes@WEI_DBA

Comment: Do your tables have the proper indexes? Or are they just indexed with the PK Identity column? Display your Execution plan for the query... This will tell you where your issues are.

Comment: i get this: /*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery30.sql - SIMISMAIN.simisdb (sa (114))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 65.9822%.
*/

/*
USE [simisdb]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[DeliveryTons] ([delivery_status])
INCLUDE ([delivery_id])
GO
*/

Comment: That's a starting point. Review the full output and see where the highest % is at. Then go down from there.

Comment: Thats the only one that says missing index. /*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery30.sql - SIMISMAIN.simisdb (sa (114))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 65.9822%.
*/

/*
USE [simisdb]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[DeliveryTons] ([delivery_status])
INCLUDE ([delivery_id])
GO
*/

Comment: Ok. So create the index and run the query again... see if it cuts down your execution time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean how do i create the index.

Comment: Do you have the power to create indexes? If so, run this in Query Analyzer, `USE [simisdb] GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DeliveryTons_Delivery_Status_IVIAS] ON [dbo].[DeliveryTons] ([delivery_status]) INCLUDE ([delivery_id]) GO`

Comment: Wow, this seems to have sped up my query. This is the first time I am using this feature to optimize. I still don't quite understand what is happening but i ran this twice on the two tables that had missing indexes and now the query are executing fast as before.

Comment: Go to https://www.brentozar.com/ and become a follower... :-) very good information there.

Comment: Remove "top (100) percent" from your views and forget that you even know about this. That directive does nothing useful and is simply a hack to allow an order by clause in a view. The optimizer knows it is useless and ignores it. In addition. rows in a view, like a table, are logically without order. If you want an ordered resultset, the query that generates it must include an order by clause. In a view, that clause is used to satisfy the top directive only - the db engine is still free to return those rows in any order it wants.

Answer (score 1):

How are your indexes?  Everything you're joining on/doing a where clause on have an index?  Experiment with columns that you use in your joins/where clauses, especially for columns of tables with the most rows.

Depending on how large your tables are too it's not recommended to just index everything it will take up a lot of unnecessary memory.  But I would go to the table with the most rows, look at what columns of it are being used in your where/joins, and make sure they are indexed.

Also, look into the `EXPLAIN` feature of [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017), it will tell you where you're doing full table scans (slow) and that can help you optimize.